# HTTP requests in Intel XDK

Tags: http, intel-xdk

I previously built an app in the Intel XDK platform pre the Feb 23rd update and now the software has updated when i try to run the emulator it just crashes.

previously i sent a get request to a process php page for a login in the following way.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('form.login').submit(function () {
var user = $(this).find("[name='user']").val();
var pass = $(this).find("[name='pass']").val();
var sublogin = $(this).find("[name='sublogin']").val();

// ...
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://www.domain.com/data/apps/project1/process.php",
data: {
    user : user,
    pass : pass,
    sublogin : sublogin,
},
 success: function(response){                       
        if(response == "1")
                    {

                     $("#responsecontainer").html(response);    

                    window.location.href = "menu.html"; 

                    }
                    // Login failed
                    else
                    {
                         $("#responsecontainer").html(response);  
                    }


        //alert(response);
    }
   });
      this.reset();
        return false;
      });
   });
```

However it seems that this is the piece of code that is causing the problems, if I remove this item of code the project no longer crashes.

When i read through the Intel XDK documents it only shows HTTP request to call XML files.

So i was hoping that somebody may know why this is causing the problem or how i might construct it so that Intel XDK doesn't crash.

Comment: I don't exactly have a solution for you yet, but if you want to go back to the previous version of the XDK you can find instructions here - https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/542074 .  That might help until we have another solution.

Comment: Thank you, that will work fine. and give me some breathing space to re-write or find the cause.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a regression bug with regards to relative location URL referenced through emulator, a fix is being worked on. This is related to emulator only. Your app should work fine with test tab using App Preview on the device and using the build.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice after i made my last comment that the problem didn't seem to exist in the app preview.  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Till we come up with a fix for emulator crash, here is a workaround. The issue arises when you are trying to change the location of your current page with window.location.href = "menu.html"; and emulator is not able to resolve the relative path during ajax call.

Please use the following code as a workaround.

```
var newLocation = 'menu.html'; 
if ( window.tinyHippos ) { 
// special case for emulator
  newLocation = getWebRoot() + newLocation;
}
document.location.href=newLocation;
function getWebRoot() {
    "use strict" ;
    var path = window.location.href ;
    path = path.substring( 0, path.lastIndexOf('/') ) ;
    path += '/';
    return path;
}
```

Swati